# Peugeot Milano, old steel

Tags: identify-this-bike, touring-bikes, commuting-bike, used-bike

I found an old Peugeot bike, can this variant be restored ?, does is real chromoly or is it a kind of steel.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t seem to be in bad condition, just check&adjust everything, lube the chain, get new handlebar grips and ride it. Maybe you’ll need new tires/tubes, cables and pedals.

Comment: The left side of the bad looks ravaged. Make sure it is sound (no gouges or groves) in case of doubt, replace. You don't want it breaking off.

Comment: I believe Carel is referring to the handlebar: I would also clean it and check for damage.  I have cleaned up a number of found-in-trash bikes and the first thing I would do is replace all outer and inner cables.  There are a lot of very cheap sets on eBay or similar that cost less than $10.  That would immediately improve braking and shifting.  Like Michael said, this bike definitely needs new grips for comfort and safety.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a great candidate for a rebuild and learning experience.

The sticker on the downtube clearly says "CroMo" meaning an alloy of steel with trace amounts of **chromium, manganese and molybdenum**.  Either way its still steel, but a different alloy.

I have a concern in the stem - it looks to be very far out of the threaded headset, so do check that it is installed far enough.  You should not see any trace of the "minimum insert" marking.

Also, someone has fitted the saddle backward and then rotated the seat post which is causing the extreme up-angle.  Flip the saddle, rotate seatpost, and it will be a lot more comfortable.

Depending on the age, you may need new brake pads and/or tyres.  But the chain may come back with some flexing and lubrication.

I'd spend as little as possible to make it work, then get some distance on it, and see what still needs work if anything.

As for age, its a tough one.  The slight dropped seat stay is generally quite a modern feature, but the brand, rake of fork, canti brakes all call out 80s touring bike but with a replacement stem and bar.   Its an intriguing bike and will be a nice ride when done, assuming its a good fit for you.

Comment: Good catch on the seat post, was wondering what happened to the seat!  To me, it looks like a typical mid-1990's "city bike" as we used to call them.  Like a touring bike setup for commuting.  Judging from the photos I would personally not waste time on the chain...

Comment: The alloy is steel with chromium, manganese and molybdenum, not chromium and magnesium.

Comment: @Andrew good point and excellent spotting - fixed, thank you.